# Updating the data in angular view that is bound to a function in .ts file everytime a change is detected

Tags: node.js, angular, express, pusher

I'm building an ecommerce app in MEAN stack. For making the app real-time, I'm using pusher-js. To display the number of a particular item in the cart, I've used a function in the ts file that iterates over all the items in a shopping-cart(which is an input property to the product-card component) and finds the number of that item in the cart and then displays it.

```html
<div *ngIf="product.name" class="card" style="width: 23rem;">
    <img *ngIf="product.url" class="card-img-top" [src]="product.url" alt="{{ product.name }}">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{ product.price | currency:'USD':true }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer" *ngIf="showActions">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <button 
                class="btn btn-secondary btn-block active"
                [disabled]="productQuantity === 0"
                (click)="removeFromCart(product)">
                    Remove
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col quantity">{{ getQuantity() }} in Cart</div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <button 
                class="btn btn-secondary btn-block"
                (click)="addToCart(product)">
                    Add
                </button>                    
            </div>
        </div>                                              
    </div>
```

This is the html file of the component. 10th line from the last indicates the use of getQuantity() function. That function is defined in the following file:

```js
import { ShoppingCartService } from './../shopping-cart.service';
import { Product } from './../models/Product';
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'product-card',
  templateUrl: './product-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-card.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
export class ProductCardComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input('product') product;
  @Input('show-actions') showActions = true;
  @Input('shopping-cart') shoppingCart;
  constructor(private cartService: ShoppingCartService) {
  }

  addToCart(product: Product) {
    this.cartService.addToCart(product);
  }

  removeFromCart(product: Product) {
    this.cartService.removeFromCart(product);
  }

  getQuantity() {
    if (!this.shoppingCart) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      const itemsArray = this.shoppingCart.items;
      for (let i = 0; i < itemsArray.length; i++) {
        if (itemsArray[i]._id === this.product._id) {
          return itemsArray[i].quantity;
        }
      }
      return 0;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Whenever I add a product to the shopping-cart, pusher-js emits an event from the server-side. I can't figure out as to when to catch the event in the angular side and then call the getQuantity() function again so that the view gets updated in real time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to listen to the pusher-js event, you should have everything in your code.

Firstly, I would define a property `quantity`, and use that in the template instead of `getQuantity()`. `getQuantity()` will then only update `this.quantity`.

Further, I would call `getQuantity()` after `cartService`'s `addToCart()` or `removeFromCart()` methods are finished. Now it depends on whether the methods return a `Promise` or an `Observable`. In case it's a `Promise` (which it probably is, since you're not calling a `subscribe` method), it would look like:

```
this.cartService.addToCart(product)
    .then(data => { 
        getQuantity(); 
    });
```

Comment: I’d also tried it the same way. But then the problem arises when the product-card is first rendered. What I did was, I first defined a property quantity and had set its value in the ngOnInit() method the same way I did in the getQuantity() method. But before the ngOnInin() method could set the value of quantity, the component got rendered and the value of quantity was undefined.

Comment: I don't understand exactly. Did getQuantity() calculate so long, that it finished only after the component was rendered and the value was undefined in-between? In that case you can set on default this.quantity = 0 (if the calculation takes that long it won't get better than that). Or did ngOnInit calculate wrong value, because it needed something, which was known only after the content was rendered? In that case there are other hooks, like ngAfterContentInit, ngAfterViewInit, that you can use instead of ngOnInit.

Comment: ngOnInit calculates the correct value but only after the view is rendered. I also tried to log the value of the quantity into the console. It showed up the correct value but before that the view rendered the default 0 value.